# How to set up hermitic tests in Julia, with per-test and/or per-fixture setup/teardown methods?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, julia

Most test frameworks in languages like Java, C++, Javascript, C#, Python include, as a core tenant, that tests should be hermetic. To that end, they provide various ways to set up the state to a known configuration before each and every test, and then do cleanup after each and every test. Although this is not foolproof, programmers generally don't have to worry about one test affecting another test.

How do I do that in Julia?

The built-in `Test` module just runs the entire test script with utter disregard for hermetic concerns on the part of the framework. Other modules I've found like [ReTest.jl](https://github.com/JuliaTesting/ReTest.jl) and [XUnit.jl](https://juliapackages.com/p/xunit) add various bells and whistles, but I haven't found anything that adds setup/teardown machinery.

Comment: You touch an important issue. However, there are many layers to what level of test separation you require. Maybe what https://github.com/YingboMa/SafeTestsets.jl does is enough for your needs?

Comment: If you really want a completely hermetically tested package, you may need to create something like a Docker session, compile Julia, and run each test from Docker.  Something like SimpleContainerGenerator would help you set that up. That level of separation is far too heavyweight to require Julia's package install system to use it when checking an installation, though. In addition, one of the benefits of testing non-hermetically is that you also get to test your own system with its quirks for odd interactions of a new package with the local installation of Julia.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Not sure what that package does, but looks like it just... wraps your module in a.. madeup module? Not sure how that helps with anything?

Comment: @Bill Docker is absolutely not what I have in mind at all. No other language needs Docker to give hermitic (or mostly hermitic) test frameworks. Let me restate: I just want something with setup() and tearDown() methods to be called before/after each and every test.

Comment: This auto-generated module introduces a fully separate namespace. What gets executed inside the module does not leak-out of the module. The only things that do leak are global state like: what you outputted to stdout, stderr etc. (this cannot be helped), state of random number generator (this is resolved by `@testset` which controls state of RNG), or other global settings if you explicitly decided to use them (e.g. changing `ENV` global variable).

Comment: @Nicu is the level of hermitic that you want one where you want to spawn a copy of Julia for each test, then? Or would you also want to rebuild the module afresh for each test?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Mm, I see. Yes I can see how that would be helpful with the hermitic part of the question, but doesn't address having per-test setup methods. Here's a particular usecase: I want to test some database code. In all tests, I want to have the DB seeded with some initial data. Some tests might only run queries and not modify the data. But others might change it, and I need a systematic way of resetting the database to that good initial state.

Comment: I realize that most test frameworks I'm familiar with are written in heavily object-oriented styles which do not fit comfortably within Julia. So perhaps the closest thing I want is some Julia version of Jasmine framework we see in Javascript/Typescript world.

Comment: So you mean test fixtures? You would typically create a function that runs the initialization steps and invoke it where needed.